# Funcion excerpt en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo la siguiente funcion excerpt en wordpress

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpdocs_excerpt_more' );

/**
    * Filter the except length to 20 words.
    *
    * @param int $length Excerpt length.
    *
    * @return int (Maybe) modified excerpt length.
*/


function wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 40;
}

add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Y yo me pregunto si es posible tener mas de una funcion excerpt para usarlar en difirentes post. La finalidad es darle diferentes largos a los post que se muestran dependiendo donde esta ubicados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si pero necesitas armar tu propio excerpt, el código que pones modifica solo la longitud del de Wordpress.

En functions.php (este código no recuerdo de donde lo tome pero es el que yo uso, ojo cuenta caracteres no palabras).

```
function my_excerpt( $my_lenght = null ){
    if( empty( $my_lenght ) ) {
        $lenght = 200; //Default value
    } else {
        $lenght = $my_lenght;
    }

    $excerpt = get_the_content();
    $excerpt = preg_replace(" ([.*?])",'',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $lenght);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'...';

    return $excerpt;
}
```

En tus plantillas dentro del loop..

```
echo '<p>'. my_excerpt(100) . '</p>';
```

En otra plantilla…

```
echo '<p>'. my_excerpt(400) . '</p>';
```

…etc

Comment: Muchiiiisimas gracias, es lo que estaba buscando.